# can you use node-inspector to debug a node.js app running with foreman

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, foreman, node-inspector

I have an node.js application that I can debug with node-inspector running:

```
node --debug app.js
```

But I want to use foreman to start my application so it will load environment variables in the .env file.  Like so:

```
foreman start
```

Is there a way to run the app with foreman and also use node-inspector?  I tried:

```
foreman start --debug
```

but didn't have any luck with that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `node --debug app.js` in your Procfile

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense and helps me understand procfiles themselves more clearly :]

Answer (score 3):

If you only are concerned with environment variables, you may also consider using:

`foreman run node --debug app.js`

The `run` command isn't exactly the same as `start`; instead of firing up your entire app, it only runs a command in the context of your app's Heroku environment. So this may or may not work depending on your situation (if you have supporting workers, etc.).